# Triangles in the corners of skybox

Tags: unity, skybox

When looking at the corners of skybox this happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGenQ.jpg

How to get rid of this?

6 skybox textures are 2048x2048px each.

Tried changing Near and Far clipping of the main camera inside the character controller but it was ineffective.

If I look away from the corners the dark triangles dissapear. Only when I look directly at the corners they appear.

Comment: Is there a separate skybox camera that you need to adjust the clipping on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screenshot I can see three different levels of the skybox, as the stars in the bottom corners are even brighter. I would guess this is related to mipmapping. Looks like different mipmap levels somehow produce different results. Try disabling mipmapping to see if the problem disappears. A possible cause for this effect could be lack of gamma correction for producing the mipmaps, which makes the blurred stars appear darker than the sharp ones.

Comment: It worked. Does turning off mipmapping make the game more system intensive?